# Stripe PaymentMethodsActivity add google pay button

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

When displaying payment methods to user using PaymentMethodsActivity how can I add google pay button to that methods list?

I know it's possible on IOS to add Apple pay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that it is not possible to add Google Pay as a payment method choice in the `PaymentMethodsActivity` (similarly to how Apple Pay could be shown as an available payment choice in the `STPPaymentMethodsViewController`).

For Google Pay you will need to show a separate Google Pay button and integrate [using this approach](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/google-pay).

Comment: Yes @psmvac, you are right, it established by stripe suupport, they say: Unfortunately, it's not possible to add Google Pay as a payment method on the PaymentMethodsActivity, if you want to make a somewhat more sophisticated activity is to actually roll your own